# Snowflake to Hive data movement with partition

Tags: hive, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have a requirement to move data from Snowflake to Hive. I am able to unload data from snowflake to aws S3 and do and msck repair on Hive.
But all records are coming as null in Hive. What could be the reason ? Is there anything wrong here .
To check the parquet is created correctly , I read the Parquet file using Spark . I am able to read the parquet file.

##Snowflake
create or replace stage dev_zone.DAILY_LOG url= 's3://myc-mlb-alpha-us-east-1-drg-322t232/hive/rs_hive_008_test1' storage_integration = DEV_HIVE_INTEGRATION file_format = (type = 'parquet') ENCRYPTION = (TYPE = 'AWS_SSE_S3');

```
copy into @dev_zone.DAILY_LOG from (select * from dev_zone.DAILY_LOG limit 100) partition by  ('as_on_date=' ||as_on_date);

##Hive 
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dev_zone.DAILY_LOG(
dim_id decimal(38,0),
card_type string,
type string,
cntry string,
PARTITIONED BY (
  as_on_date date)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://myc-mlb-alpha-us-east-1-drg-322t232/hive/rs_hive_008_test1'
```

Answer (score 1):

What I missed was to add header = true

```
copy into @dev_zone.DAILY_LOG from (select * from dev_zone.DAILY_LOG limit 100) partition by  ('as_on_date=' ||as_on_date) header = true;
```

Comment: Just for my own interest, what is your use case for moving data out of Snowflake and into Hive?

Comment: @NickW , Business want to keep the data in Hive as well. After three months of the business, they want to delete data from Snowflake managed table. Once we moved to hive this data can be accessed as Snowflake external table ( for Critical business users) and for others they can access thru Hive - ( Hive runs on EMR ) So no additional cost for processing on hive except reading s3 bucket. Hope I answer your question.